# second time click does not working using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I have list dynamically generated through php code. I want to delete rows by clicking. My code working fine just first time, on second time

### HTML

```
                    <li>
                        <div class="pers-left-container">
                            <img src="<?php echo $cProduct['thumb']; ?>" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="pers-right-container">
                            <span class="sidebar-product-name"><?php echo $cProduct['name']; ?></span>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close-container-product  removeItem">X

                            <form id="removeItemForm" method="post" >
                                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $cProduct['product_id']; ?>" name="removeProductId"  class="removePID" />
                            </form>
                            </a><br />
                            <label>Qty: </label><input type="number" value="1" min="0" max="100" step="5" /><br />
                            <span class="price-container-product">Amt: <?php echo $cProduct['price']; ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>


                    </li>
```

### JS

```
$( ".removeItem" ).each(function(index) {
                $(this).click("click",  function(){

                    //var otherInput = $(this).find('.pID').val();
                    removePID = {'removeProductId':$(this).find('.removePID').val()}
                    alert(removePID['removeProductId']);
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"index.php?route=common/personaliseyourflowers",
                        data:removePID,
                        success:function(response){
                            //alert(response);
                            if(response) {
                                $(".reloadCOnt").load(window.location + " .reloadCOnt");
                            }
                            //} else {
                                //$(".reloadCOnt").load(window.location + " .reloadCOnt");
                            //}
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Can any one guide me where i'm wrong.  I will thanks

Comment: Try $(this).on("click", instead of $(this).click("click",

Comment: @monace19 yes I have already tried this `$(this).on("click",` but i was facing same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.click inside .each?!!  use `$('body').on('click' , selector , function(){});`

```
$( 'body' ).on("click",".removeItem",  function(){

       //var otherInput = $(this).find('.pID').val();
       removePID = {'removeProductId':$(this).find('.removePID').val()}
       alert(removePID['removeProductId']);
       $.ajax({
       type:"post",
       url:"index.php?route=common/personaliseyourflowers",
       data:removePID,
       success:function(response){
                //alert(response);
                if(response) {
                  $(".reloadCOnt").load(window.location + " .reloadCOnt");
                 }
                 //} else {
                   //$(".reloadCOnt").load(window.location + " .reloadCOnt");
                 //}
               }
      });
});
```

Comment: yes I'm using each because i have dynamically generated li listing so how you code will work ?

Comment: @AyazShah while you use a classes each element with this class can has its own click by the same code without need to repeat the code in .each

Comment: Unbelievable result. Its working but i'm wondering how it is working because we are not using any each function. Thanks

Comment: @AyazShah yes as I told you click event will work with elements with the same class   in your case its ".removeItem"  so any element has this class  this click event will work with it .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Think there is a problem with event delegation,

Change

```
$(this).click("click",  function(){
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", ".removeItem", function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on click function, and events to prevent href :

```
$( ".removeItem" ).click(function(e) {
                   e.preventDefault(); // to stop redirecting to href 
                   //var otherInput = $(this).find('.pID').val();
                   removePID = {'removeProductId':$(this).find('.removePID').val()}
                   alert(removePID['removeProductId']);
                   $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"index.php?route=common/personaliseyourflowers",
                        data:removePID,
                        success:function(response){
                            //alert(response);
                            if(response) {
                                $(".reloadCOnt").load(window.location + " .reloadCOnt");
                            }
                            //} else {
                                //$(".reloadCOnt").load(window.location + " .reloadCOnt");
                            //}
                        }
                    });
            });
```

Comment: Thank for guideline but i'm facing same issue using your code

Comment: @AyazShah are you getting `alert(removePID['removeProductId']);` alert all the time

Comment: Good Question, I'm not getting alert on all time just first time it is giving alert

Comment: just need to check a thing so please do a change in your code, remove the class `removeItem` and add `id=removeItem`, and do changes in your jquery as well from `$( ".removeItem" ).click(function(e) {` to `$( "#removeItem" ).click(function(e) {`